# Why Would Doppl Fail To Find a Unit Test Class?

Tags: doppl

When trying to run JUnit tests for a Doppl-converted project, I am crashing with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'JavaLangRuntimeException', reason: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.doppl.so.RepositoryTest'
```

So, the JUnit code is failing to find my test class (`co.doppl.so.RepositoryTest`).

The class is included in my `dopplConfig`:

```
dopplConfig {
  translatePattern {
    include 'co/doppl/so/api/**'
    include 'co/doppl/so/arch/**'
    include 'co/doppl/so/RepositoryTest.java'
  }

  translatedPathPrefix 'co.doppl.so', 'SO'
  translatedPathPrefix 'co.doppl.so.api', 'SOAPI'
  translatedPathPrefix 'co.doppl.so.arch', 'SOA'

  testIdentifier {
    include 'co/doppl/so/RepositoryTest.java'
  }
}
```

I see `SORepositoryTest.h` and `SORepositoryTest.m` in `app/build/j2objcSrcGenTest/`. The `prefixes.properties` file seems correct:

```
#Sat Oct 28 14:44:00 EDT 2017
co.doppl.so=SO
co.doppl.so.arch=SOA
co.doppl.so.api=SOAPI
```

The `dopplTests.txt` lists the class that cannot be found:

```
co.doppl.so.RepositoryTest
```

My `ViewController.swift` file is pulling in that `dopplTests.txt` file:

```
import UIKit
import testdoppllib

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CoTouchlabDopplTestingDopplJunitTestHelper.runResource(with: "dopplTests.txt")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Why would Doppl's JUnit stuff fail to find this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be [a bug/limitation/something](https://github.com/doppllib/doppl-gradle/issues/12) with the current Doppl, where tests cannot be renamed using `translatePathPrefix`.